# im trying to build my app using flutter but android studio keeps giving me this error

Tags: flutter, android-studio

this is the error message i keep getting.
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\rayha\AndroidStudioProjects\flutterapplication\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\rayha.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\3d075fs9hjp81ny0sgym4v09w).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

i tried changing my version of java like some comments suggested but it didnt work.

Comment: try to open C:\Users\rayha\AndroidStudioProjects\flutterapplication\android\ as android project with Android Studio and run gradle build, then open flutter project and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to the following directory `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle` and delete `wrapper` folder. This contains your cache files.

Once you delete that folder, come back to your android studio project and run the following commands, one after one.

```
flutter clean
cd android
./gradlew build wrapper
flutter pub get
flutter run -v
```

If you get any errors, post here.

Comment: thank you. i reinstalkled my python and set another path on env variables. but im thinking to cache files must have cleared itself when i did that.